# How to check for certain USB disk activities on windows?

Tags: forensics, usb-storage

I used FTK images to take image of the documents and registry files for a PC.
I want to check for certain USB disk , when the last time it was used and when it was unplugged and activities during that time if possible .
What is the right tool\method to do so ?

Comment: This is more of a Windows OS question than an InfoSec question. Although you want to apply the answer to an InfoSec application, the question itself is an OS operational question.

Answer (score 0):

At my workplace we use a [NIRSoft tool called USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html).  With its command line arguments, we pull out the device name, VID/PID, install time & date of the driver, time of insertion, type of USB device (disk, external CD-ROM, 4G modem, etc.), vendor, volume GUID, volume name (eg. "F:\"), instance ID/serial #, and some other details.

We use this to trace whether malware was brought in on a non-company USB drive during an incident response, and could use it to enforce our company's USB policy.

Comment: Thanks ..I tried to use that tool . however it is giving me inconsistent results .
i.e. i ran the program on the first pc to take the USB's serial ,then i ran it on the pc that i want to know when it was last used on it .
And yet there was no match between the serials